# Como borrar todos los registros de una tabla de SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito borrar todos los registros de una tabla de SQLServer sin indicar cual quiero borrar, quiero que sean todos y este código me elimina datos en especifico

```
 delete from tbl_usuarios where nombre='Abi';
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante simple y básica, de hecho es un error común cuando empiezas con SQL, hacer el DELETE SIN WHERE.... de lo mas feo que le puede pasar a alguien que va iniciando. [Delete sin WHERE - Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_cVJgIz_Cs)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Del query que estas realizando puedes quitar desde el **where** en adelante

**Tu codigo:**

```
delete from tbl_usuarios where nombre='Abi';
```

**Tu codigo modificado:**

```
delete from tbl_usuarios;
```

**Otra Opción es utilizar TRUNCATE**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_usuarios;
```

Pero es importante que conozcas las diferencias entre **delete** y **truncate**, aquí te comparto una tabla de las diferencias (Fuente:[Diferencias entre delete y truncate](https://grimpidev.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/diferencias-entre-truncate-table-y-delete-from/))

[image: Diferencias entre delete y truncate]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu informacion!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Pues basta con quitar el `WHERE` que es la condición bastaria con:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_usuarios
```

Fuente: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Basta con que pongas `DELETE FROM *Nombre_de_tu_tabla*`

Answer (score 1):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_usuarios
```

te serviría.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el código Truncate, tienes que tener en cuenta es que si lo utilizas debes verificar que la tabla donde realizarás Truncate no tenga constraints de Foreing Key, si es te es el caso deberás quitar las relaciones que afectan a la misma antes de realizar Truncate, si es tabla que es referenciada por otras a través de una llave foránea, deberás revisar si el impacto de eliminar los registros en la tabla no afecta, y si este es el caso establece la eliminación en cascada solo para estos efectos, a continuación te muestro un ejemplo;

Esta tabla es la tabla padre

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Id ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Esta es la tabla hija

```
CREATE TABLE Detalle
(
    Id_detalle int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Id int NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT PK_Detalle PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Id_detalle ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY
GO
ALTER TABLE FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir FOREIGN KEY(Id)
REFERENCES Prueba (Id)
GO 
ALTER TABLE Detalle CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir 
GO
```

La tabla detalle hace referencia a Id de la tabla prueba, lo que corresponde en este caso para mayor facilidad colocar la eliminación en cascada, o sea que, si se elimina un registro en la tabla Prueba, todos los registros se eliminarán en las tablas que hacen referencia a este campo en la tabla Prueba, primero deberás modificar el Constraint antes, y modificar su acción en eliminación y si quieres en actualización, por fines de demostración colocaré el constraint incluyendo acción al actualizar (aunque aquí no sea el caso),

```
Alter Table Detalle
Drop Constraint FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir
GO
```

Luego de eliminar el Constraint procedes a crear el nuevo...

```
Alter Table Detalle
Add Constraint FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir Foreign Key (CampoHijo) References MiTablaPadre(CampoPadre) On Update Cascade On Delete Cascade
```

Luego de esto podrás realizar sin ningún problema Truncate en la tabla y no te generará un error, esto si es en ambiente de desarrollo y no en producción (la base de datos del cliente con su información ya interactuando con los usuarios a través de una aplicación), después puedes regresar las políticas de eliminación a que no realice nada al eliminar como están por defecto haciendo el mismo procedimiento de eliminar el Constraint modificado...

```
Alter Table Detalle
Drop Constraint FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir
GO

Alter Table Detalle
Add Constraint FK_MiTablaHija_RegistroTablaPadreDebeExistir Foreign Key (CampoHijo) References MiTablaPadre(CampoPadre) On Update No action On Delete No action
```

Listo... aquí ya regresaste la relación como estaba antes de realizar Truncate...

Este link te puede ayudar a ver lo que se escribe arriba...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/3bb52114-9c6e-48b5-bb1c-a6e360e23f8a/actualizar-y-eliminar-en-cascada-sql-server-2005?forum=sqlserveres